# Why does the OnPostLoad not fire in AppEngine (JPA 1.0)

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I've attached the `javax.persistence.PostLoad` annotation to my method `private void onPostLoad()` in a class annotated with `javax.persistence.Entity` in my Google AppEngine project using JPA 1.0 (I've checked the *Use Datanucleus JDO/JPA version "v1"* in the Google
 AppEngine properties in the Eclipse project for compatibility reasons). The method does not fire after I perform a SELECT query using the `javax.persistence.Query.getSingleResult()` method. Why not?

Its counterpart `@OnPrePersist` works just fine though. I've also tried loading the object using `entityManager.find()`, to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something ancient (v1 of Google's plugin) is your own choice, even though it was superceded (with backwards compatibility upgrade path) with v2 more than a year ago. Simple viewing of their issue tracker shows 
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=210&can=1&q=postload&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20FoundIn%20TargetRelease%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that since I'm using Jersey for REST endpoint generation, which requires asm-3.3.1.jar, which in turn collides with the asm-4.jar included with v2 of datanucleus. But thanks for the heads up.